# Switching between StoryBoards programmatically based on locale

Tags: ipad, ios5, storyboard, right-to-left

I have two storyBoards one for LTR(Left to Right Scripts like english , german etc) and one for arabic RTL(Right to left scripts). I want to switch between these two storyboards based on the user language selected. Currently im executing this code in AppDelegate.m file :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSString *typeN = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
//NSBundle *myBundle= [[NSBundle alloc] init];

if([typeN compare:@"ar"] == NSOrderedSame){
    UIStoryboard *us = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RtlStoryboard" bundle: nil];
   FirstViewController *myStoryBoardInitialViewController = [us instantiateInitialViewController];
    myStoryBoardInitialViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        NSLog(@"arabic- RTL");
}
else {
    UIStoryboard *ms = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

   FirstViewController *myStoryBoardInitialViewControl = [ms instantiateInitialViewController];
    myStoryBoardInitialViewControl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
     NSLog(@"english- ENG");

}
```

Is this the right way of doing it, though for arabic [typeN compare:@"ar"] if block is getting executed But it is still loading LTR storyBoard. Also the view controllers are same for both storyboards, because the code logic is same, its just the screen formatting is different. Please provide pointers or detail me on this issue.